# Partial rendering (no header/footer) of a page in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, renderpartial

I'm working in ZF2 and have worked in Yii. What I want to know is if there's any way for rendering a page partially, like in Yii. I mean rendering only the code on view page and not adding header & footer to the rendered view. I'm trying this to render a view page in a different module/controller using ajax.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous, you need to use renderPartial functionality in zend or yii? If you want to use in zend, please remove yii tag.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can disable the layout on a view model, which will tell the renderer to only render the specific view you return from your controller action.

```
public function doSomethingCrazyAction()
{
    $view = new ViewModel(array(
        'message' => 'Hello world',
    ));

    // Disable layouts; `MvcEvent` will use this View Model instead
    $view->setTerminal(true);

    return $view;
}
```

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html

Comment: Thank you very much dualmon for your time and energy. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Did that solve it for you? You can accept my answer if it did.